# Show/Hide Menu underline accelerators with PyQt according to platform integration

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to make a PyQt application work as the other Qt applications I have on my system (i am on KDE plasma on linux).

A notable difference is that in the application I am making the accelerator character for the menu entries always appears underlined while in all the other Qt applications I have on my system the underlining only appears when the ALT key is pressed (e.g. in KDE okular).  I see that other PyQt application seem to have the same behavior as mine (e.g., spyder).

The Qt reference guide says that Qt should automatically manage the underlining according to the platform integration, but this does not seem to be the case with my PyQt app.

Does someone know why this is the case and how to obtain the platform standard behavior?

Comment: Are you setting the application style (through `app.setStyle(...)`), or are you using stylesheets? What is the output of `QApplication.style().objectName()`?

Comment: I am not using `app.setstyle(...)`. My expectation was that without it the platform setting would have been taken. By checking the `QApplication.style().objectname()` I get `fusion` though, which is not my platform default (`breeze`).

Is there a standard way to pick the platform default in a portable (Linux, Windows) way?

Comment: Mh, that's strange. By default, Qt prefers the system default, unless specific conditions are set (environment variables, command line arguments). How did you set the platform default? Is any other program created with PyQt (so we could check their behavior against that of your program)?

Comment: @musicamante One thing that I note is that other PyQt applications (e.g. `spyder`) have the same behavior. Differently from the rest of the platform they show the underlinings all the time.

Comment: @musicamante, I have a hypotheses, can you help me understand if it makes sense? When I install PyQt5 in a virtual env, it pulls in a local copy of the Qt libraries that cannot access the system-wide theme `breeze`. Does it make sense? I am suspecting that this is the case because if I try to manually switch to `windows` that works, but if I try to switch to `breeze` that does not work.

Comment: Ah, the virtual env. This might be a hint. See [this bug report]: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1195

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the pointer.

I have made more tests and this is definitely an issue related to the use of virtual envs. I think I can also explain it:

The platform styles (e.g., breeze) only work with the platform Qt library. When you install PyQt or PySide in a virtual env via pip this brings in another version of the Qt libraries (via PyQt5-Qt or directly embedded in PySide2), That won't use the platform widget style support but default to `fusion`.

Comment: Hence, I suspect that python Qt applications running in virtual environments will never look nicely platform integrated (at least on linux) unless you create the virtual environment so that it can access the system-wide python packages and you do not install anything that pulls in PyQt or PySide in your virtual environment.

In this way apps in the virtual environment will use the platform supplied Qt libraries that can access the platform supplied styles.